# Magento2 Custom Page Builder, doesn't render widgets on frontend

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, page-builder

I have a problem with the page builder on my custom module. In the adminhtml, everything is working fine, and my code propeller is saved to DB, but when I'm trying "echo" my code, the widget isn't displayed. I can see for example `{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Page\Link" anchor_text="test" title="test" template="widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="1"}}`  instead of my widget. Does anyone know how to render this code?

Comment: @dundan did you found a solution for this ?

Comment: @KrzysztofLinetty yes, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider;
```

I fixed this issue with:

```
public function generateHtmlWithWidgets($html): string
{
    return $this->getCmsFilterContent($html);
}

private function getCmsFilterContent($value = ''): string
{
    return $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($value);
}

public function _prepareLayout(): Column
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

and on .phtml file:

```
  $pageBuilder = $block->getPageBuilder();
  echo $block->generateHtmlWithWidgets($pageBuilder);
```

Comment: @MagentoDev2 Your last edit breaks formatting. Please do not put normal text into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\CustomProductAttribute\ViewModel;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Product implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var GetBlockByIdentifierInterface
     */
    private $blockByIdentifier;

    /**
     * @var BlockRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $blockRepository;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var FilterProvider
     */
    private $filterProvider;

    /**
     * @param FilterProvider $filterProvider
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param GetBlockByIdentifierInterface $blockByIdentifier
     * @param BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        GetBlockByIdentifierInterface $blockByIdentifier,
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
    ) {
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->blockByIdentifier = $blockByIdentifier;
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Return Block from ID
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @return BlockInterface
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockById(string $id)
    {
        return $this->blockRepository->getById($id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting block from blockIdentifier
     *
     * @param string $blockIdentifier
     * @return string
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getBlockFromIdentifier(string $blockIdentifier)
    {
        $block =  $this->blockByIdentifier->execute($blockIdentifier, (int)$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        return $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter($block->getContent());
    }

    /**
     * Getting label of product attributes
     *
     * @param object $product
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProductAttributeLabel($product, $attributeName)
    {
        return $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeName)->getFrontendLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Getting value of product attributes
     *
     * @param object $product
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProductAttributeValue($product, $attributeName)
    {
        return $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeName)
            ->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    }
}
```